# How to make a method return type as Callable<Boolean>

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, callable-object

In one of my methods:

```
public void pageIsReady()
```

the implementation is

```
Awaitility.await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(isPageLoaded());
```

Here, `isPageLoaded()` method returns boolean value, but I want it to return a  `Callable` of Boolean, because the `until()` method in `Awaitility` expects `Callable<Boolean>`.

Please help me to make the method `isPageLoaded()` return `Callable<Boolean>`

Here is the implementation of `isPageLoaded()` method:

```
protected Boolean isPageLoaded() {
    String jsQuery = "function pageLoaded() "
            + "{var loadingStatus=(document.readyState=='complete');"
            + "return loadingStatus;};"
            + "return pageLoaded()";

    boolean isSuccess = false;
    try {
        isSuccess = (Boolean) evaluateJavascript(jsQuery);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to use a method reference `Callable<Boolean> isPageLoaded = this::isPageLoaded`, or to use it explicitly as lambda `Callable<Boolean> isPageLoaded = () -> isPageLoaded();`

This would look like

```
Awaitility.await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(this::isPageLoaded);
Awaitility.await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(() -> isPageLoaded());
```

Another way would be to define your method as returning a `Callable<Boolean>` and then using lambda syntax `() -> {}` to write the callable.

```
protected Callable<Boolean> isPageLoaded() {
    return () -> {
        String jsQuery = "function pageLoaded() "
            + "{var loadingStatus=(document.readyState=='complete');"
            + "return loadingStatus;};"
            + "return pageLoaded()";

        boolean isSuccess = false;
        try {
            isSuccess = (Boolean) evaluateJavascript(jsQuery);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isSuccess;
    };
}
```

Lambda expressions and method references can be quite powerful tools.

Comment: Thanks. Its working!!. I used the below one. Awaitility.await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(isPageLoaded());

Answer (score 0):

Just define your `isPageLoaded()` method as follows:

```
protected Callable<Boolean> isPageLoaded() {
    //code..
}
```